# How do I submit an XCode bug to Apple?

Tags: xcode, swift

As a developer, I have come across a few bugs in Xcode and Swift, which don't lead to crashes, and thus don't report the errors to Apple. I'm talking about crashes of my app where the exception raised is not visible in the log (ex. wrong cast) or the error by the compiler is just wrong (calling a class func from a variable initializer).

Where do I submit these to Apple?

Examples:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/wD11R.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDysB.png (while log is empty, no error whatsoever)

Comment: This one is nice too: `2015-02-24 11:11:57.922 Heaven Help[4339:559405] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Heaven_Help.FreeTopUpToggleTableViewCell 0x15ed1be0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key creditsLabel.'` when you have an outlet that is no longer in your code but still in your storyboard.

Comment: That isn't a bug. That would be a feature request in my opinion.

Comment: Yeah, but you can't submit a feature request through <apple.com/feedback> for Xcode/Swift. So I'm making a bugreport.

Comment: Apple has just released 6.3 Beta 2. Fixed many bugs. You should download it first and check if it has been already fixed.

Comment: @vrwim I'm going to be honest I don't see how either of the bugs that you say are bugs for Apple are anything to do with Apple. They seem more like issues with your code especially the one in your comment. I think we need more detail from you that illustrates why it is a bug for Apple.

Comment: @Popeye I know that the errors I provide are bugs with my code, but Xcode does not provide helpful information in these cases. That's why I see them as bugs in Xcode. Especially the illegal cast that does not give anything in the log.

Comment: @vrwim this is how the `xcode IDE` has always been so in this case it's not a bug report that needs raising because they will reject it as a bug because its not its a feature request. And bugs in code are a lot more descriptive if you look through the stack trace and not just the logs. You can also create your own exception handling pretty easily that will provide you with the information that you want in the console. So if you want more information in the console just write some exception handling like you would if developing in Java or any other programming language.

Comment: @vrwim Just a quick note, the first example you have given isn't a bug. The reason you get an error is that you haven't initialised `Test` yet.

Comment: @GabrielJones I know, but the bug is that it isn't obvious that methods are internally given another parameter when they are performed on objects. If this error occurred in more complicated code, it would be very frustrating to the developer to see that a method needs a parameter while it obviously doesn't. This error should say that an object reference is required when an instance method is called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple provides some informations on their website [how you can send bug reports](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) to them. The best way is to use the [Apple Bug Reporter.](https://bugreport.apple.com/problem/viewproblem)

[How to use the bug reporter.](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/using-bug-reporter/)

Answer (score 2):

If you have an Apple developer account, go to http://bugreporter.apple.com and you can file your bug (with screenshots) there.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for:

https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/